# Free chess engine

Tags: engines

I was surprised to learn that you can download and use Shredder for free. I was also surprised to learn that a GUI is required and needs to be downloaded separately. I was happy to learn that you can find some decent-looking chessboard GUIs for free on the internet. My question is: once I download Shredder and the appropriate GUI, what do I need to do to get them to work together?

Comment: That's dependent on the GUI.  Try SCID.

Comment: That is a GUI, right? My question is: how do I connect the engine to the GUI once I've downloaded both?

Comment: Read the instructions, it is all there. And SCID comes with several engines including Stockfish 4.

Comment: Also try ChessBase Reader: http://en.chessbase.com/pages/download

Comment: @overtheboard this may be good, but is it free?

Comment: Yes, ChessBase Reader is free.

Comment: @overtheboard Chessbase is impressive and aesthetically pleasing. Thanks for the tip. Was fairly easy to connect to stockfish once I downloaded it and also easy to analyze games.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using GUI menu, you have to show engine filepath. Thats all.

Every GUI is different but there should be something like "add engine" where you can browse and select engine binary file.

Comment: Thank you. I guess with enough playing around with it, I might have been able to figure it out. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

Out of topic, but if you want free chess engine with ready UI and very powerful engine, I would reccommend you to use [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/).

Comment: OK. When I went on the Stockfish website, they said I needed to download a GUI separately. Do they really have an "all-in-one" package?

Comment: It appears that they provide an integrated "all-in-one" - but only for Mac.  So if you have a Mac, you could be in luck...

Comment: I'm afraid I don't. You had me really excited for a moment there. :)

Comment: SCID comes with Stockfish 4. It's GM or near GM strength.  Download Stockfish 6. Then open SCID and use the Tools->engines (or some such) to configure the location of Stockfish 6. It is not too hard.

Comment: @MattCremeens at the wors you can get it on your phone. for Androids, it is called Droidfish. For iphones - Stockfish

Answer (score 0):

You have to use http://es.lichess.org/analysis
It´s free and good.

Comment: have to use?  is there a gun to his head or what?